# Unknown alignment for access: / SLP: step doesn't divide the vector-size

Tags: gcc, vectorization

Unknown alignment for access: / SLP: step doesn't divide the vector-size.
I am trying to auto vectorize a nested loop. The vectorizer output suggests that the outer loop is vectorized, but not the inner one.

```
vectorizer throws out the following error-

/src/vectest.cpp:104: note: SLP: step doesn't divide the vector-size.
/src/vectest.cpp:104: note: Unknown alignment for access: *stack1.0_22
/src/vectest.cpp:104: note: vect_compute_data_ref_alignment:
/src/vectest.cpp:104: note: SLP: step doesn't divide the vector-size.
/src/vectest.cpp:104: note: Unknown alignment for access: rsum1
/src/vectest.cpp:104: note: vect_compute_data_ref_alignment:
/src/vectest.cpp:104: note: SLP: step doesn't divide the vector-size.
```

The following is the snippet of code :

```
rsum1[yi]=rsum;
gsum1[yi]=gsum;
bsum1[yi]=bsum;
asum1[yi]=asum;
routsum1[yi]=(int)routsum;
goutsum1[yi]=(int)goutsum;
boutsum1[yi]=(int)boutsum;
aoutsum1[yi]=(int)aoutsum;
yi++;
}
```

All the variables are declared as int. 
I am compiling for arm and the variables should be aligned to the machine default.

Could some one help me understand this error message better ?

The compiler is arm-linux-androideabi-g++ (GCC) 4.8

The complete source is uploaded here:

```
[1]http://pastebin.com/8Q1t6apg
```

I have checked the following two links, though the concept of alignment is clear, I fail to understand the error in my case.

```
[2]https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html#using
[3]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096599/gcc-vectorization-difference-between-two-similar-loops#new-answer
```

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3 does not show the error . It seems to have successfully vectorized, though it says that "1 loop is vectorized".  I would have expected it to vectorize two loops.