# Why can GCC not vectorize this function and loop?

Tags: c++, vectorization, openmp, simd, auto-vectorization

I'm attempting to make a function SIMD-enabled and vectorize the loop with a function call.

```
#include <cmath>

#pragma omp declare simd
double BlackBoxFunction(const double x) {
    return 1.0/sqrt(x);
}

double ComputeIntegral(const int n, const double a, const double b) {
    const double dx = (b - a)/n;
    double I = 0.0;
    #pragma omp simd reduction(+: I)

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      const double xip12 = a + dx*(double(i) + 0.5);
      const double yip12 = BlackBoxFunction(xip12);
      const double dI = yip12*dx;
      I += dI; 
  }
  return I;
}
```

For the code above, if I compile it with `icpc`:

```
icpc worker.cc -qopenmp -qopt-report=5 -c
```

The opt-report shows that the function and loop are both vectorized.
However, if I try to compile it with `g++ 6.5`:

```
g++ worker.cc -O3 -fopenmp -fopt-info-vec-missed -funsafe-math-optimizations -c
```

The output shows `note:not vectorized: control flow in loop.` and `note: bad loop form`, and the loop cannot be vectorized.

How can I vectorize the loop with GCC?

**EDIT :**

If I write the function into a separate file,

`worker.cc`:

```
#include "library.h"

double ComputeIntegral(const int n, const double a, const double b) {
    const double dx = (b - a)/n;
    double I = 0.0;
    #pragma omp simd reduction(+: I)

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      const double xip12 = a + dx*(double(i) + 0.5);
      const double yip12 = BlackBoxFunction(xip12);
      const double dI = yip12*dx;
      I += dI; 
  }
  return I;
}
```

`library.h`:

```
#ifndef __INCLUDED_LIBRARY_H__
#define __INCLUDED_LIBRARY_H__

#pragma omp declare simd
double BlackBoxFunction(const double x); 

#endif
```

and `library.cc`:

```
#include <cmath>

#pragma omp declare simd
double BlackBoxFunction(const double x) {
  return 1.0/sqrt(x);
}
```

Then I compile it with GCC:

```
g++ worker.cc library.cc -O3 -fopenmp -fopt-info-vec-missed -funsafe-math-optimizations -c
```

It shows:

```
worker.cc:9:31: note: loop vectorized
```

but

```
library.cc:5:18: note:not vectorized: control flow in loop.
library.cc:5:18: note:bad loop form.
```

It makes me confused. I wonder whether it is already vectorized.

Comment: [Relevant GCC source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-6_5_0-release/gcc/tree-vect-loop.c#L1310). You can see that it raises the control flow warning if there are more than two [basic blocks](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Basic-Blocks.html) inside the loop, counting the loop machinery as one of them. I'd guess that means the function call is splitting the loop contents into two or three blocks; if you manually inline `BlackBoxFunction` does it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCC: vectorization difference between two similar loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096599/gcc-vectorization-difference-between-two-similar-loops)

Comment: @Rup I tried but GCC still gives the hint that `control flow in loop` and `bad loop form`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vectorization is possible with gcc, after some slight modifications of the code:

```
#include <cmath>

double BlackBoxFunction(const double x) {
    return 1.0/sqrt(x);
}

double ComputeIntegral(const int n, const double a, const double b) {
    const double dx = (b - a)/n;
    double I = 0.0;
    double d_i = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      const double xip12 = a + dx*(d_i + 0.5);
      d_i = d_i + 1.0;
      const double yip12 = BlackBoxFunction(xip12);
      const double dI = yip12*dx;
      I += dI; 
  }
  return I;
}
```

This was compiled with the compiler options: `-Ofast -march=haswell -fopt-info-vec-missed -funsafe-math-optimizations`. The main loop compiles to

```
.L7:
    vaddpd  ymm2, ymm4, ymm7
    inc     eax
    vaddpd  ymm4, ymm4, ymm8
    vfmadd132pd     ymm2, ymm9, ymm5
    vsqrtpd ymm2, ymm2
    vdivpd  ymm2, ymm6, ymm2
    vfmadd231pd     ymm3, ymm5, ymm2
    cmp     eax, edx
    jne     .L7
```

See the following [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/oO2AH0)

I removed the `#pragma omp ...`, because they didn't improve the vectorization, but they did not made the vectorization worse either.

Note that only changing the compiler option from `-O3` to `-Ofast` is
sufficient to enable vectorization. Nevertheless, it is more efficient to use a `double` counter than an `int` counter which is converted to double each iteration.

Note also that the vectorization reports are quite misleading. Inspect the generated assembly code to see whether or not the vectorization was successful.

Comment: You can also consider starting with `double xip12 = a + 0.5*dx;` outside the loop, and increment with `xip12 = xip12 + dx;`, which would be slightly more efficient.

Comment: It works, thank you. I used to think only `-O3` or `-O2 -ftree-vectorize` can enable vectorization. But in this case, these compiler options didn't work. Does it mean that `-Ofast` is a better choice to enable vectorization?

Comment: Option `-Ofast` enables both `-funsafe-math-optimizations` and `-fno-math-errno`. In order to vectorize the `sqrt`, you need `-fno-math-errno`. In the vectorized case, the additions are ordered in a different way than in the scalar case. Therefore you also need the `-funsafe-math-optimizations`, because floating point additions are not associative. With a more simple `BlackBoxFunction`, the code already vectorizes with only `-O2  -funsafe-math-optimizations -ftree-vectorize`, [see this Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/keBGWn) .

Comment: Without specifying compiler options such as `-mavx2` or `-march=haswell`, the compiler uses SIMD instructions up to the SSE2 instruction set. Usually AVX or AVX2 code is faster than SSE2 code, but you need processor support obviously. Note that the division and square root instructions are not fully vectorized by the current AMD and Intel processors. So, in this particular case, the performance difference between SSE2 and AVX(2) vectorized code is probably relatively small.

Comment: @pangbryant: worth mentioning that ICPC enables fast-math by default, somewhat similar to `gcc -O3 -ffast-math`.  OpenMP pragmas can allow auto-vectorization of FP reductions *without* `-ffast-math` (just `-O3`), but not in this case.  Perhaps if you only used `-fno-math-errno` to allow `sqrt` to fully inline, gcc would be able to auto-vectorize the reduction thanks to   the pragma enabling optimizations that change the order of summing the result.  (FP math is not strictly associative because of different rounding from different summation orders.)

Comment: Also worth mentioning that there's little enough work *other* than SQRTPD and DIVPD that it's very heavily bottlenecking on that.  Using an approximate reciprocal (even with a Newton iteration) would be a *lot* faster, especially with 256-bit vectors. But there's no `rsqrtpd`, only `ps` (`float`).  The FP divider unit is only 128 bits wide in most Intel CPUs, so div and sqrt don't gain much if any throughput from wider vectors.

Comment: @PeterCordes, parallelization requires associativity. I think OpenMP only enables floating point associative math. It does not need to enable or assume other "unsafe" math options.

Comment: @PeterCordes, what do you meant that "FP divider unit is only 128 bits wide in most Intel CPUs"? Do you mean that with AVX512 if I do a float point division that on a zmm register internally it's implemented as four 128-bit operations (e.g. like SSE 4 times)?

Comment: @Zboson: That's what I was trying to say: OpenMP enables associative math for just that loop, without enabling the rest of `-ffast-math` or any 
unsafe / fast-math options for the rest of the code.  Apparently it doesn't even enable no-math-errno to allow inlining `sqrt`.

Comment: @Zboson: KNL is the exception to "most", but yes look at Agner Fog's insn table: SKX's `divps` throughput is scalar/xmm: 3c, ymm: 5c, zmm: 10c.  But xmm and ymm both have 11c latency, with ZMM having 18c latency.  The `double` numbers for `[v]divpd` throughput are 4, 8, and 16c throughput.  So it's normal for the dividers to be about half width, not fully pipelined.  On KNL, SSE xmm is 32c latency / 20c throughput, while AVX-anything is apparently 32/32 regardless of float/double.  Xeon Phi has AVX512ER because divide throughput is garbage.

Comment: @Zboson: Peter's comment is illustrated by [this Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/CtFseF). The loop vectorizes with `#pragma omp simd reduction(+: I)`, but not with `#pragma omp simd` (without the `reduction(+: I)`, unless the `-fassociative-math`, `-fno-signed-zeros`, and `-fno-trapping-math` options are added to gcc.